# fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python

I am trying to install mysqlclient, but I get this error message:

> _mysql.c:40:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>       compilation terminated.
>   error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Could anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: which system? you need python developement headers for the compilation

Comment: on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: So use apt-get to install mysql client, and python-dev if you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the python development package (which contains the C headers files) for your OS (on debian-based distros it's named 'pythonX.X-dev' where 'X.X' is python version).